# Full window-layout with scrollable column does not work only in Firefox - what is wrong?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to create full-window layout with scrollable content pane and floating panel on the left. I've started with css tables and was rather happy with the outcome in Chrome and IE11. The problem is: it totally does not work at all in Firefox. What did I miss?

I've structured the page like this:

```
<div class="column-container">
    <div class="column" style="width: 200px;">1st column</div>
    <div class="column" style="position: relative; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
            ... (lot's of rows)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And used styles:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;
}

.column-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's fiddle with a bit more colors: http://jsfiddle.net/GWsLJ/3/

Comment: What version is your Firefox?

Comment: Newest - 25.0.1. On both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the reason why Firefox does not let me do proper scrolling using css tables. The answer of zsaat14 was working good apart from width of content pane - couldn't get that working without javascript (resizing window / jquery ui's resizable on panel).

What did work for me was absolute positioning of panel and content (as in zsaat14's answer) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWsLJ/22/). Also I was setting .absolute-div's left to the width of sidebar.

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.column-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

.absolute-div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:200px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure out what was going on with your code in firefox.  I was able to get this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWsLJ/16/) to work.  I ended up simplifying your HTML and moving all styling over to CSS.  It works in all major browsers.

The HTML:

```
<div class="column-container">
    <div class="sidebar">lol</div>
    <div class="absolute-div">
        <!--content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0px;
}
.column-container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 200px;
}
.absolute-div {
    display: table-cell;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:200px;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
}
```